# Wordpress custom post type's categories just stopped working

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

We haven't changed anything and for some reason wordpress will no longer keep the category settings for new or updated posts.

We have created a custom post type: 'member'
with a custom taxonomy for that type: 'business type'

We have around 200 posts in that type, and today when adding a new one I would select the categories it belonged to, click publish, and it then removed those categories from being selected..

We've tried logging out, and logging back in, updating wordpress, and tried with multiple posts.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It randomly started working again with no changes..